# HTML Sidebar p tags move main content area down

Tags: html, css

I have a system where there is a sidebar on the left and a main content area on the right.  When I go to add some p tags to the sidebar, it moves the entire content area down several lines.  I want to have the sidebar and content area aligned.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t60Lk8ra/1/
(it doesn't display everything correctly but you can see the problem, the two bars need to be aligned)

Code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="left">
   sidebar1

    <p class="set">placeholder</p>

    <p class="set">placeholder</p>

    <p class="set">placeholder</p>

    <p class="set">placeholder</p>

    <p class="set">placeholder</p>
</div>

<div class="right">
    sidebar2
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div.left{
width:20%;
height:98%;
background-color: #787F6C;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 1%;
margin-right: 1%;
display : inline-block;

}
div.right{
width:75%;
margin-right: 1%;
height:98%;
background-color: white;

display : inline-block;
}

.set{
width: 92%;
margin-top: 3%;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
height: 20px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #D5F4C8;

}
body{
    background: #D5F4C8;
    margin:0;
}
```

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: If you add a `float:left;` to both sections you'll be in a much better place, i.e. `.left { float: left; }` and `.right{ float:left; }`

Comment: Thanks, That worked!

Comment: Make sure you understand how floats work. It will nullify a lot of other positioning properties :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*float* and *align* both work however the css also has to be adjusted a little for everything to be evenly aligned with gutters & margins.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="left">sidebar1
    <p class="set">placeholder</p>
    <p class="set">placeholder</p>
    <p class="set">placeholder</p>
    <p class="set">placeholder</p>
    <p class="set">placeholder</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">sidebar2
    <p class="set">placeholder</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
div.left {
float: left;
width:20%;
background-color: #787F6C;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 1%;
display : inline-block;
}
div.right {
float: right;
width:75%;
background-color: #ffffff;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-right: 1%;
display : inline-block;
}
.set {
width: 92%;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
height: 20px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #D5F4C8;
}
body {
background: #D5F4C8;
margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [float](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)

```
float:left;
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

Just add `vertical-align: top` so you don't have to rely on floats:

```
div.right {
  vertical-align: top;
  ...
}
```